# Проблема с форматированием текста из файла

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qlabel, textformat

Я извлекаю текст из файла, где есть строки в тегах `<b>` и `<i>` и вставляю его в приложение, но в итоге текст получается в исходном формате (с этими тегами, без жирного шрифта и курсива).

Как исправить?

`label.setText(SplitLineFile.split_line('lessons.txt')[number] )`

[image: в приложении PyQT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**textFormat : Qt::TextFormat**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop)
>
> Это свойство содержит текстовый формат `label`. 
> См. перечисление [**Qt::TextFormat**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextFormat-enum) для объяснения возможных опций.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QLabel("""
        x18
        <br>x19<br>
        <b>Hello <i>World</i></b>""")
        
        self.label.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)       # <---- попробуйте закомментировать

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]